# struct and values entered in C

Tags: c, output

I have a program that does not work. The problem for example is:

You input 2 for students, then enter mark 5 for the first student and then  10 for second student.

The output sum in the `fun()` function should return 15 . But instead, it returns 20.

This is my code so far:

```
struct mark{
   int x;   
};

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of student: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    struct mark *marks= malloc(n * sizeof(struct mark)); ;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        printf("Enter mark: ");
        scanf("%d",&(*marks).x);
    }

   fun(marks,n);

    free(marks);
    return 0;
}

void fun(struct mark *marks, int n){
    int sum =0,i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        sum= sum+(*marks).x;

    }
    printf("Sum: %d \n",sum);

}
```

Comment: If it is C (as stated in the title, why the C++ tag?)

Comment: I tried hammering this into shape a tad.

Comment: Use marks[i] instead of (*marks).

Comment: You're always writing and reading the first `mark`. Note that in the two `for` cycles you're not making use of the index `i`. Instead you should use the index to select the correct `mark` in the `marks` array. For example `scanf("%d",&marks[i].x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    scanf("%d",&(*marks).x);
```

Means you are reading into the first `mark` in `marks`.

You already have a for loop and a counter variable for reading into it, so use it. change

```
sum= sum+(*marks).x;
```

to

```
sum= sum+marks[i].x;
```

which is also equivalent to

```
sum = sum+(*marks+i).x;
```

Do the same for

```
scanf("%d",&(*marks).x);
```

change it to

```
scanf("%d",&marks[i].x);
```

again,

`marks[i].x` is equivalent to `(*marks+i).x`

The point is that you want to access the second `mark` in `marks` in your second iteration of your for loop. Also, don't forget to `free()` your `marks` when your program is done.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
scanf("%d",&marks[i].x);
```

and:

```
sum= sum+marks[i].x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `main` in this piece of code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        printf("Enter mark: ");
        scanf("%d",&(*marks).x);
    }
```

You are always assigning mark to 1st array element.

Inside `fun` in this piece of code:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
        sum= sum+(*marks).x;
    }
```

you are not iterating over the marks array, but instead always reading 1st array value.